# New font in Alfresco Share Preview

Tags: fonts, import, share, alfresco, preview

Is there a way to import a new font to the preview?
Also, whenever I transform a Word document to PDF, during the transformation the generated PDF document is with different font. This distorts the document formatting.

Can someone help me how to import a font in Alfresco?

Thank you

Comment: Which previewer are you using? Alfresco Transformation Server? OpenOffice? JODConverter? Other?

Comment: A think is Alfresco Transformation Server

Comment: Did you ensure that the fonts used are installed on the Windows machine that the transformer service is installed on?

Comment: Yes, all fonts are installed on the system. However, when the document is previewed the content is with totally different than the original.

Comment: I'd suggest you give Alfresco support a call, that's what you're paying all that money for Enterprise + Transformation Server for!